# Must declare the scalar variable "@vigencia_desde"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have anoying problem with an insert in sql server.
The error is:

**Must declare the scalar variable "@vigencia_desde".**
sometimes appears another variable:
**Must declare the scalar variable "@fecha_nac".**

These columns in sql server table are DATE

Ill show you how i do it.

```
      if (Conexion() != null) {
           Response.Write("Conectado");

           SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();

           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
           {  
               conexion = Conexion();
               command.Parameters.Clear();


               command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO IngT_Persona (Nombre, Rut, Fecha_nac, Estudios, Gerencia, Cargo, Jefe, Vigencia_desde,Vigencia_hasta, Correo, Lista_distribucion, tipo_tarjeta, Tajeta_casino, Tarjeta_fotocopia, caso_casino, caso_imp_fotoc, req_equipo, Caso_equipo, Apli_crm, Apli_QV, Apli_fin700, Apli_SAP, equipo_tel, salida_cel, larga_dist_n, larga_dist_int, no, Anexo, Caso_tel, Obs, Fecha_creacion, usuario) VALUES (@nombre, @rut, @fecha_nac, @estudios, @gerencia, @cargo, @jefe, @vigencia_desde, @vigencia_hasta, @correo, @lista_distribucion, @tipo_tarjeta, @tarjeta_casino, @tarjeta_fotocopia, @caso_casino, @caso_imp_fotoc, @req_equipo, @caso_equipo, @apli_crm, @apli_qv, @apli_fin700, @apli_sap, @equipo_tel, @salida_cel, @larga_dist_n, @larga_dist_int, @no, @anexo, @caso_tel, @obs, @fecha_creacion, @usuario)";
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut);

              // DateTime date_fecha_nac = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha_nac, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
               DateTime date_fecha_nac;
               if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
               {
                   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", DateTime.Today);
               }

               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estudios", estudios);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gerencia", gerencia );
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo", cargo );
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jefe", jefe_directo);

               DateTime date_vigencia_desde;
               if (DateTime.TryParse(vigencia_desde, out date_vigencia_desde))
               {
                   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_desde", DateTime.Today);
               }

               DateTime date_vigencia_hasta;
               if (DateTime.TryParse(vigencia_hasta, out date_vigencia_hasta))
               {
                   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_hasta", DateTime.Today);
               }

               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", correo);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lista_distribucion", lista_dib);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_tarjeta", tarjeta);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarjeta_casino", casino);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarjeta_fotocopia",impres_fotoc);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caso_casino", caso_casino);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caso_imp_fotoc", caso_imprec_fotoc);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_equipo", req_equip);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caso_equipo", caso_equip);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apli_crm", crm);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apli_qv", qlikview);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apli_fin700", fin700);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("apli_sap", sap);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@equipo_tel", equip_tele);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salida_cel", salida_cell);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@larga_dist_n", larga_dist_nac);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@larga_dist_int", larga_dist_int);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", chk_no);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anexo", anexo );
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caso_tel", caso_fono);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obs", observ);
               //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_creacion", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")); 
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_creacion", DateTime.Today);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", Session["logon"] );


               try
               {
                  // connection.Open();
                   command.Connection = conexion;
                   int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   Response.Write("ingresado a la tabla"); 
               }
               catch (SqlException ex)
               {
                   except = ex.Message;
                   Response.Write(except); 
               }
               finally
               {
                   conexion.Close();
                   Response.Redirect("INGRESO.aspx");
               }
           }

       }

       else
       {
           Response.Write("nO HUBO CONEXION"); 
       }
```

I hope your help
regards

Comment: Looking at your code it seems pretty clear that if the TryParse fails the two parameters are not added to your query.

Comment: not directly related to your question, but what's the point of parsing values for date your parameters if you're just going to set them to `DateTime.Today` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, all of the parameters that are causing this problem have something in common: they are all included inside an `if` statement:

```
DateTime date_fecha_nac;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", DateTime.
}
```

If your `TryParse` fails, you will never define that parameter, but you still try to use it in your `INSERT` statement. That causes SQL to fail because it doesn't know what you're talking about when you tell it to insert `@fecha_nac` but don't define the parameter.

If you are going to use the parameters in your query, you **always** have to add it to the `command.Parameters` collection. You can either pick a default value to use if your `TryParse` fails:

```
DateTime date_fecha_nac;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", fecha_nac);
}
else
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", DateTime.Today);
}
```

or, if those fields are NULL-able in SQL, you can just not set a value for the parameters you don't want:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@fecha_nac", SqlDbType.DateTime);

DateTime date_fecha_nac;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
{
    command.Parameters["@fecha_nac"] = date_fecha_nac;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only sometimes including these paramaters in your command, but they are required for your insert.  You need to figure out what to do if your try parse fails, maybe these should be null?

e.g.

```
DateTime date_vigencia_desde;
if (DateTime.TryParse(vigencia_desde, out date_vigencia_desde))
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_desde", DateTime.Today);
} else 
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_desde", System.DbNull.Value);
}
```

Would also note that your logic looks off - if you parse the date correctly you set this parameter to today - is that what you mean to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are conditionally adding parameters but they are required by your query. Do the following instead:

```
DateTime date_vigencia_desde;
if (DateTime.TryParse(vigencia_desde, out date_vigencia_desde))
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_desde", DateTime.Today);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vigencia_desde", DBNull.Value);
```

And so on and so forth for the other conditionally added parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In these lines, if the condition fails you don't add the parameter to the collection resulting in the error message

```
DateTime date_fecha_nac;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", DateTime.Today);
}
```

so you need an else condition where you add a default value

```
else
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", ????);
}
```

However it seems that you have written it in the reverse way. If the TryParse returns true then the conversion has been successful and you probably want to set the value of the parameter to the converted datetime

```
DateTime date_fecha_nac;
if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha_nac, out date_fecha_nac))
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", date_fecha_nac);
}
else
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nac", DateTime.Today);
}
```

The same happens for the other parameters (`@vigencia_hasta` and `@vigencia_desde`) that are added as a result of conversions